# How to stop automatic upgrade of postgres,mongodb and RHE7 itself?

Tags: rhel, rpm, upgrade

I have installed Postgeresql, mongodb using `yum` in RHEL 7.0 few days back, but now they are automatically upgrading. I don't want it to happen. How can I prevent the automatic upgrades?

Comment: There's a yum extension for package pinning IIRC

Comment: Even in RHEL7, updates shouldn't be applied without you running a yum command. Are you registered in a Red Hat Satellite Server ?

Comment: Yes I am registered with Red Hat,one year subscription

Answer (score 1):

Add following line to your `/etc/yum.conf`:

`exclude=postgresql mongodb`

P.S.: I'm not sure about `mongodb` you should check the package name with `rpm -qa | grep mongo` for example.

Comment: Solution to stop upgrade of RHEL 7  link : https://access.redhat.com/support/cases/#/case/01508969?commentId=a0aA000000EpGYlIAN

Comment: @user124665 the link requires you to log in into redhat support center.